# What does the diaper's wetness indicator actually test for?

Tags: diaper

A number of diapers (we are using pampers) advertise a wetness indicator. Does this simply indicate moisture or urine itself? I have heard people saying that this is useful for tracking wet diapers specifically but I don't know if it actually functions like that.

Comment: It is just a general moisture test, not specifically urine. Can I ask, why would it matter how the diaper got wet?

Comment: I wanted to know if it was a urine indicator rather than a general wetness indicator because we are tracking how often the baby has stool and how often she has urinated. It is difficult to determine whether or not she urinated when she also had a stool

Comment: im going to throw a guess out for electrical continuity / internal resistance.
after reading user4050's comment, i bet there is a difference in continuity. try a remote sensor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the indicator simply reacts to moisture, not urine specifically.
If you're prepared to sacrifice a diaper, you could simply test it with water.

When my son was born, the hospital had Pampers diapers with a wetness indicator. When "off" it was invisible, and when the diaper was wet (used), a vertical blue line appeared on the outside of the diaper. This is a very clever way to show first-time parents that the diaper needs changing.

These diapers seem to be special hospital merchandise. I was not able to find them in stores, at least not here in Austria. I missed the indicator because it's so efficient, but we quickly learned to live without it anyway.

Comment: The most popular manufacturers of nappies/diapers in the UK sell ranges with animals that become visible (I think dolphins and teddy bears) when wet, encouraging the child to alert the parents earlier rather than waiting.

Comment: I have yet to see a diaper that doesn't have this indicator. US

Comment: @longneck wait until your kid is in 3's or higher (well, "Cruisers"/"Little Movers" or higher).  For some reason, those don't have an indicator anymore.

Comment: @Charles - Several reasons. First, you're supposed to keep count of a newborn's wet and soiled diapers, and you get the best count by changing them as soon as you notice the blue, instead of letting a couple of movements stack up. With older kids you simply change as necessary. Also, bigger diapers are more absorbent and your kid's skin a little less sensitive by this stage, so you can let a slightly wet diaper go. There will also be other signs of a diaper that *needs* changing by this point. Lastly, by this size, parents are supposed to be experts in diagnosing a wet nappie.